# Equivalent command(s) to stage all changes and commit to master in VS Code source control

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

I want to make an npm script to push all my code to the master branch of a GitHub repository and deploy to my hosting provider. The command to deploy is working but the push to GitHub is not.

It is as follows:

```
git push origin master:master
```

I want the command to be the equivalent of navigating to Source Control in VS Code, staging all changes, and clicking "Commit & Sync." What command do I use for this?

Comment: I guess it would need to be: `git commit -a -m "Here's a comment"; git push origin @`

Comment: @eftshift0 I am getting: `fatal: paths 'git ...' with -a does not make sense`

Comment: If you are providing paths to `git commit`, then `git commit -a` does not make sense. I guess we need the full command/commands and the full output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using:

```
git add -A
&& git commit -m messageHere
&& git pull
&& git push https://github.com/github-username/repositoryName
```